# Java Swing BufferedImage vs Direct Drawing

Tags: java, swing

My scenario is basically that I am drawing a mathematical type plot with horizontal and vertical scales.  For any given window size, the scales remain static.  I only need to change the scales if the user resizes the window.  I was therefore debating whether drawing the scales on a BufferedImage and calling drawImage is better than doing all of the individual drawXXX calls to construct the scales on each paint.  The latter does not sound very efficient since the user will likely resize the window once at startup (if that) but the trade off would be the memory required to maintain a BufferedImage that could be as big as 4K display resolution

If anyone has any thoughts/opinions/suggestions, I would appreciate hearing them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would be using `TYPE_INT_ARGB` for the `BufferedImage` format, an image that is of "4k" resolution (3840x2160) would be 33.18 MBs in size (that's mega**Bytes**) + maybe a few bytes for header info.

So, really, it wouldn't be that much of a memory concern.  But, remember, either way, you will have to be repainting to either the `BufferedImage` or to the `Graphics` object every time it calls `paint()`.  Truly, I see no significant difference in efficiency.

The only real difference I see here is that with `BufferedImage` you get the added comforts of its built in resizing capabilities.  This way you can always paint your scales onto the image the same way (**Not have to do calculations based on window size**) then resize the `BufferedImage` to the window size and it takes care of resizing the scales to fit the window on its own.